# Moving object with mouse

Tags: qt, drag, qlabel

I use Qt and I want to move some object with mouse. For example, user clicks on object and drag this object to another place of window. How I can do it?

I tried mouseMoveEvent:

```
void QDropLabel::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    this->move(ev->pos());
}
```

but unfortunately object moves very strange way. It jumps from place to place.

QDropLabel inherits QLabel. Also it has given a pixmap.
I tried to do it with different objects, but result is same.

Comment: Mouse move event is not for "mouse is dragging something" but literaly mouse (cursor) moved. You have to catch "dragging" somehow. Also ev->pos may be relative to widget

Comment: I don't want to use it for drag and drop. I just want to move object using mouse.

Comment: Ok, but you want object to follow cursor by itself, or make it movable

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your movable widget must have a `QPoint offset` member. It will store a position of the cursor click relative to the widget's top left corner:

```
void DropLabel::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    offset = event->pos();
}
```

On mouse move event you just move your widget in its parent coordinate system. Note that if you don't subtract `offset` from the cursor position, your widget will 'jump' so its top left corner will be just under the cursor.

```
void DropLabel::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        this->move(mapToParent(event->pos() - offset));
    }
}
```