# Draggable QWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I have a MainWindow.cpp class with multiple images displayed that emit a clicked() signal. Once clicked on I want to open a widget that's a fixed size inside MainWindow and I want this widget to be able to be dragged around as long as it stays inside the MainWindow class.

I was looking at example code to try and write this widget class, in particular the [Qt MainWindow Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/mainwindows-mainwindow.html). However, once one of the dockwindows are dragged around the display the Operating System specific titlebar (which lets you maximize, minimize, and close the window) gets displayed. I do not want this titlebar to be displayed.

How would I go about creating this class of draggable widgets?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172420/moving-object-with-mouse/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [setTitleBarWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdockwidget.html#setTitleBarWidget)

Setting to a void widget will work:

```
It is not possible to remove a title bar from a dock widget. 
However, a similar effect can be achieved by setting a default constructed QWidget 
as the title bar widget.
```

Edit: 
  By request:

```
yourDockableWidget->setTitleBarWidget( new QWidget( yourDockableWidget ) );
```

In the example you are following, you could do it in constructor:

```
ColorSwatch::ColorSwatch(const QString &colorName, QWidget *parent, Qt::WindowFlags flags)
: QDockWidget(parent, flags)
{
/*...*/

setTitleBarWidget( new QWidget( this ) );

/*...*/
}
```

Now your widget wont have SO titlebar when undocked;

Comment: Can you expand on the second part of your post?

Comment: Edited to add parent to QWidget, so it will destruct itself when paretn