# Is there a way to interrupt a mouse dragging programmatically in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qgraphicsscene

I would like to retain the ability of a user to zoom and drag a `QGraphicsScene`, thus I cannot simply lock the `QGraphicsView`.
However a user should not be able to drag a `QGraphicsItem` out of the scenes viewport. Therefore I am looking for a way to interrupt a MouseDragEvent without ignoring the DragMoveEvent (aka have the `QGraphicsItem` jump back to its origin point). I have tried to accomplish this behaviour using the `releaseMouse()`-function but that didn't work at all. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about Qt, but check out SetCapture and ClipCursor in the Win32 API.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172420/moving-object-with-mouse
maybe override mouseMoveEvent for that purpose?

Comment: *drag a QGraphicsItem out of the scenes viewport* - A QGraphicsItem lives in a QGraphicsScene, you can't drag it out of the scene's viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with qt graphics scene view frame work and dragging, it is better to re-implement  QGraphicsItemand::itemChange than dealing with mouse directly.

This is the function defined in header file:

```
protected:
virtual QVariant itemChange( GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant & value );
```

Then in the function, you detect the position change, and return the new position as needed.

```
QVariant YourItemItem::itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant & value )
{
     if ( change == ItemPositionChange && scene() ) 
     {
           QPointF newPos = value.toPointF(); // check if this position is out bound

    {
        if ( newPos.x() < xmin) newPos.setX(xmin);
        if ( newPos.x() > xmax ) newPos.setX(xmax);
        if ( newPos.y() < ymin ) newPos.setY(ymin);
        if ( newPos.y() > ymax ) newPos.setY(ymax);
        return newPos;
    }

   ...
}
```

Something like this, you get the idea.